# Regular expression parsing pseudo-columnized data in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, parsing, text

I'm working on a project where we're trying to parse information out of reroute advisories issued by the FAA. These advisories are issued as free text with a loosely-identified structure, with the goal being to allow viewers to print them out on a single sheet of paper.

The area of most interest is the final portion of the advisory that contains specific information related to a given reroute - the origin and destination airport as well as the specific required route that applies to any flight between them. Here's an example:

```
ORIG                DEST                ROUTE
----                ---------------     ---------------------------
FRG                 MCO TPA PIE SRQ     WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE 
                    FMY RSW APF         WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4
```

What I'd like to do is be able to parse this into three entries like this:

> **ORIG**: FRG
>
> **DEST**: MCO TPA PIE SRQ FMY RSW APF
>
> **ROUTE**: WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4

Here are the three code segments I'm currently using to parse this portion of the advisories:

Origin

```
regexp_substr(route_1,'^(([A-Z0-9]|\(|\)|\-)+\s)+')
```

Destination

```
regexp_substr(route_1,'(([A-Z0-9]|\(|\)|\-)+\s)+',1,2)
```

Route String

```
regexp_substr(route_1, '\s{2,}>?([A-Z0-9]|>|<|\s|:)+<?$')
```

While these expressions can deal with the majority of situations where the Origin and Destination portions are all on the first line, they cannot deal with the example provided earlier. Does anyone know how I might be able to successfully parse the text in my original example?

Comment: So... what's the input here? A plain ASCII file divided into rows and columns, with two header rows, and then the row order has meaning (the ORIG column being NOT NULL flagging new database rows)? How do you know where a fragment of DEST ends and a fragment of ROUTE begins in each line of plain text? Are the left edges of the columns at fixed positions? Is the input over multiple pages, with the two header rows repeated on each page? You see - you need to provide more info (unless you are looking for someone who has worked with EXACTLY this format before - good luck with that!)

Comment: It's my first time posting here so I'll keep what you've said in mind for future posts. As to your questions, The data being read in is a single column in a Oracle database that contains the entire text of the advisory. The only way I have of delineating the "columns" in the free text is by counting the number of spaces -- if more than two spaces exist (or the end of a line), then my logic assumes that the end of an entry has been reached. The issue I'm having is that some of the entries - the destinations and the routes - can carry over onto multiple lines.

Comment: OK, that is a lot clearer. I see a big problem though: if you really have only ONE column, there is no room for an "order" marker. How do you know which rows go together? Rows in a table are like balls in a basket - there is no way to know in what order the balls were put in the basket, if the balls aren't marked somehow. If you had a way to order the rows, you could probably use some of the code (and approach, more generally) I demonstrated in my Answer. First split the text lines into columns (as I did straight from the text file) and then further process as shown in the Answer.

Comment: @PhilSchrader - do you mean that an entire advisory is stored as a single varchar2 or CLOB value; so one row in the table per advisory? If so you could process that CLOB line by line in PL/SQL and build up the three values. Also, looking at your example and other advisories, it seems to be possible for any or all of the three 'fields' to split onto multiple lines. I'm not sure how you'd separate them if all three did (even as a human...) Can that happen, and do they add a blank line or something if it does? I don't think your 2-spaces rule is right either (look at #069 today).

Answer (score 1):

Proof of concept.

Input file is a plain text file (with no tabs, only spaces). Vertically it is divided into three columns, of fixed width: 20 characters, 20 characters, whatever is left (till the end of line).

The first two rows are always populated, with the headers and `-----`. These two rows can be ignored. Then the rest of the file (reading down the page) are "grouped" by the latest non-empty string in the ORIG column.

The input file looks like this:

```
ORIG                DEST                ROUTE
----                ---------------     ---------------------------
FRG                 MCO TPA PIE SRQ     WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE 
                    FMY RSW APF         WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4

ABC                 SFD RRE BAC         TRIO SBL CRT              

POLDA                                   FARM OLE BID ORDG BALL
                                        BINT LFV

YYT                 PSS TRI BABA        TEN NINE FIVE
                    COL DMV

SAL                 PRT DUW             PALO VR22 NOL3
```

Notice the empty lines between blocks, the empty `DEST` in one block (I handle that, although perhaps in the OP's problem that is not possible), and the different number of rows used by `DEST` and `ROUTE` in some cases.

The file name is `inp.txt` and it resides in a directory which I have made known to Oracle: `create directory sandbox as 'c:\app\sandbox'`. (First I had to `grant create any directory to <myself>`, while logged in as `SYS`.)

The output looks like this:

```
ORIG  DEST                        ROUTE                                              
----- --------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
FRG   MCO TPA PIE SRQ FMY RSW APF WAVEY EMJAY J174 SWL CEBEE WETRO DIW AR22 JORAY HILEY4 
ABC   SFD RRE BAC                 TRIO SBL CRT                                           
POLDA                             FARM OLE BID ORDG BALL BINT LFV                        
YYT   PSS TRI BABA COL DMV        TEN NINE FIVE                                          
SAL   PRT DUW                     PALO VR22 NOL3
```

I did this in two steps. First I created a helper table, `INP`, with four columns (RN number, ORIG varchar2(20), DEST varchar2(20), ROUTE varchar2(20)) and I imported from the text file through a procedure. Then I processed this further and used the output to populate the final table. It is very unlikely that this is the most efficient way to do this (and perhaps there are very good reasons not to do it the way I did); I have no experience with `UTL_FILE` and importing text files into Oracle in general. I did this for two reasons: to learn, and to show it **can** be done.

The procedure to import the text file into the helper table:

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE read_inp is
f UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
s VARCHAR2(200);
rn number := 1;
BEGIN
f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('SANDBOX','inp.txt','r', 200);
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(f,s);
      INSERT INto inp (rn, orig, dest, route)
      VALUES
      (rn, trim(substr(s, 1, 20)), trim(substr(s, 21, 20)), trim(substr(s, 41)));
      END;
      rn := rn + 1;
    END LOOP;
exception
  when no_data_found then 
            utl_file.fclose(f);
END;
/

exec read_inp
/
```

And the further processing (after creating the `REROUTE` table):

```
create table reroute ( orig varchar2(20), dest varchar2(4000), route varchar2(4000) );

insert into reroute
  select max(orig),
         trim(listagg(dest , ' ') within group (order by rn)),
         trim(listagg(route, ' ') within group (order by rn))
  from   ( 
           select rn, orig, dest, route, count(orig) over (order by rn) as grp
           from   inp
           where  rn >= 3
         )
  group by grp
;
```